# Помогите с запятыми в стихотворении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Не знаю, правильно ли расставила запятые. Я в 7 классе, знаний по пунктуации ещё недостаточно, но пытаюсь писать стихи... Помогите, пожалуйста.

---

"Сказка, с названием "Ложь""

Рождение - счастье, а жизнь - это смех?
Нелепо, не верю я этим словам,
Рождение - слезы, а жизнь - это грех.
Ты так не считаешь? Я что, не права?

Вы врали мне много, возможно, везде,
Наивно считая, что так будет лучше.
Я мир полюбила таким, как во сне,
Но сон этот миром жестоким разрушен.

Бесценна вам ложь, я уже поняла,
Вы сказкой моё погубили доверие.
Когда была младше, я Деда ждала,
Но Дед не пришёл... к сожалению.

Когда была младше, меня вы в детдоме
грозились оставить одну и навечно.
За то что забыла прибраться я в доме?
За то, что была я глупа и беспечна?

Я помню, как страстно чего-то желала,
Лежала, мечтала, ждала того дня,
Но вдруг обещание стало обманом,
И только "ну ладно" промолвила я.

Мне было так больно, обидно, печально,
Досадно за то, что вся жизнь - это ложь.
Меня ведь тогда ото лжи отучали
И будто растили, держа в руке нож.

Но разве так сложно сказать детям правду?
Ведь даже в пять лет я бы всё поняла.
Мне было так тошно, когда я рыдала,
Желая услышать простые слова:

"Прости, я боялась, меня не поймешь ты,
Ведь даже меня порой жизнь вводит в дрожь.
Но лучше не буду губить тебя в сказке,
Которой дала бы название "Ложь"."

Answer (score 2):

Катюша, расставить запятые нетрудно, а другие знаки Вам не интересны? Кавычки, к примеру?

Да! "Но Дед не пришёл... к сожалению", - нарушен размер. Можно, конечно, сделать мхатовскую паузу на месте многоточия, но спокойнее читается: "Но Дед не пришёл, к моему к сожалению".

"Ведь даже меня порой жизнь вводит в дрожь" - строка, перегруженная звуками.

И вот это: "И будто растили, держа в руке нож". Но растили-то не будто, перед нами живая поэтесса, вопросы задаёт; по смыслу - растили будто с ножом наготове... Катюша, призадумайтесь, а вдруг я права? О_о

Я поправлю всё, не трогая тела текста.

---

**Сказка, с названием "Ложь"**

Рождение - счастье, а жизнь - это смех?

Нелепо, не верю я этим словам,

Рождение - слезы, а жизнь - это грех.

Ты так не считаешь? Я что, не права?

Вы врали мне много, возможно везде,

Наивно считая, что так будет лучше.

Я мир полюбила таким, как во сне,

Но сон этот миром жестоким разрушен.

Бесценна вам ложь, я уже поняла,

Вы сказкой моё погубили доверие.

Когда была младше, я Деда ждала,

Но Дед не пришёл... к сожалению.

Когда была младше, меня вы в детдоме

грозились оставить одну и навечно.

За то, что забыла прибраться я в доме?

За то, что была я глупа и беспечна?

Я помню, как страстно чего-то желала:

Лежала, мечтала, ждала того дня,

Но вдруг обещание стало обманом,

И только "ну ладно" промолвила я.

Мне было так больно, обидно, печально,

Досадно за то, что вся жизнь - это ложь.

Меня ведь тогда ото лжи отучали

И будто растили, держа в руке нож.

Но разве так сложно сказать детям правду?

Ведь даже в пять лет я бы всё поняла.

Мне было так тошно, когда я рыдала,

Желая услышать простые слова:

"Прости, я боялась, меня не поймешь ты,

Ведь даже меня порой жизнь вводит в дрожь.

Но лучше не буду губить тебя в сказке,

Которой дала бы название "Ложь".

Answer (score 1):

Очень понравились стихи!

Согласен с Галиной. Что всадили нож *как будто,* но не растили так, тоже подумал. Добавлю лишь три момента, которые, на мой взгляд, надо поправить ещё.

**1.** В конце второй строчки я бы поставил точку вместо запятой.

**2.** Для лучшего ритма я бы написал *доверье* и *сожаленье* с мягким знаком. И — да, добавил бы "моему", как предлагает Галина:

Бесценна вам ложь, я уже поняла,
Вы сказкой моё погубили доверье.
Когда была младше, я Деда ждала,
Но Дед не пришёл... к моему сожаленью.

**3.** Ну и, наконец, кавычки в конце я бы сделал разными и закрыл бы и те и другие. При этом точка в любом случае ставится после всех кавычек:

«Прости, я боялась, меня не поймешь ты,
Ведь даже меня порой жизнь вводит в дрожь.
Но лучше не буду губить тебя в сказке,
Которой дала бы название "Ложь"».